# Use IF condition for different rules in gantt chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a shift plan in form of a gantt chart in excel. I have different "employees" which have to work either sequential or in paralell. The shift plan is scheduled by hours. Each employee has got a different color and name. What works for now is the following:The bars are created, when I set the start time and the end time. I used for example these rules: H$10=MEDIAN($E21;$F21;H$10), and formatted it with a color. what I'm not able to do is the following: I tried to write an If Statement like "if employee= Willi use rule1 with colore blue, else use rule2 with color yellow"

```
=IF(C$15="Willi";G$10=MEDIAN($D15;$E15;G$10);C$15=MEDIAN($D14;$E14;G$10))
```

this if statement returns FALSE.

[image: ShiftPlan]

It should return the colored bar in the correct time sequence.
The three bars(blue,green and yellow has been formated via "Conditional formatting") What I want to approach is the following: If the name of cell C15 is Willi, than take the rule of the green bar. Like in the picture. 
[image: Rule GreenBar]

If not, than take the rule of the yellow bar. I hope, you can help me.

EDIT:

This is the result, when I use the following rule: 
=IF(C$15="Willi";MEDIAN($D15;$E15;G$10);MEDIAN($D14;$E14;G$10))

EDITED:

[image: =AND(C18="Willy";MEDIAN($D18;$E18;G$10))]

Comment: What does D21 contain exactly?

Comment: Hi, It means Cell D21. So if the value of cell D21 is Willi, than do the rule. thanks for asking.

Comment: So you have put "wiili" as well as "willy" so that will cause an error. I actually asked what was in cell D21... because if it has a space it wn’t be classed as equal...

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, I'm sorry. Willi was a typo in the comment. I already tested the rule with a simple: =IF(D21="Willy";TRUE;FALSE) --> it returnes TRUE. the rule H$10=MEDIAN($E21;$F21;H$10) is also correct, but somehow all together :  =IF(D21="Willy";H$10=MEDIAN($E21;$F21;H$10);H$10=MEDIAN($E14;$F14;H$10)) is returns FALSE

Comment: maybe the If statement expects a string as a result and not a defined rule?

Comment: What do you expect the if() to do to cell H10?

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it is more clear now. thank you for your time.

Comment: The G$10=MEDIAN(...  is a comparison, so when you want to use it in the if() don't put the G$10= , just start with median(..) so =IF(D21="Willy";MEDIAN($E21;$F21;H$10);MEDIAN($E14;$F14;H$10)) should work

Comment: Hi, now I 'm getting a numeric value. instead of the colored bar, I want. But nevermind. Still thank you for your help. I will continue manually.

Comment: You mentionned in your 2nd response to Solar Mike that your two formulas work independently. Why not use AND(D21="Willy", H$10=MEDIAN($E21;$F21;H$10))? This will return a TRUE if both formulas are True and should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Pomul, thank you for your suggestion and sorry for my delayed answer. It works, but not the way I want it to work. The Bar is created with the rule you suggested, but only for the first cell. Not for the range 24.06.201915:00-24.06.201917:00 I uploaded a screenshot. thank you